# Displaying information from a table then showing related information from another table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have 2 tables.

One is a table (nameinfo) that consists of contact information (account, name, email, address, city, state, zip, tags)

Table Two is an events tables (events) (email, event_type, event_name, date, keywords)

Here is what I am trying to do...

I would like to show a list of all the events that the person went to based on the matching email address. I would like to return the results like this...

nameinfo person 1
     events person 1 went to

nameinfo person 2
    events person 2 went to

nameinfo person 3
    events person 3 went to

```
     $query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nameinfo WHERE account='$a'");

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))


    { 
     $i++;

        echo "<div>";
        echo "<table><tr style='font-weight:bold;color:green;font-size:9pt;text-align:left;'><td  style='text-align:left;'
        >";
       echo "<button class='toggles' id='".$i."'/>"; echo $row['fullname']."</button>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td  >";
        echo $row['target'];
        echo "</td><td >";
        echo $row['lname'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td >";
        echo $row['fname'];
        echo "</td><td >";
        echo $row['title'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td >";
        echo $row['company'];
        echo "</td><td >";
        echo $row['address'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td >";
        echo $row['address2'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['city'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['state'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['zip'];
        echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>";
        echo $row['email'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['officenum'];
        echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>";
        echo $row['cellnum'];
        echo "</td>";
          echo "<td>";
        echo $row['date'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['rep'];
        echo "</td></tr></table></div>";
        echo "<div style='width:100%;background:#000;color:#fff;display:none;' id='show-".$i."'>";
        **echo THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO PUT THE EVENT INFORMATION BUT HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO DO IT.;**
        echo "</div>";
    }    

<script>
$("button.toggles").click(function() {
       var value = $(this).attr('id');
       $("#show-" + value).toggle();
}); 
</script>
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Does the event table have a column with data in common with the nameinfo table?

Comment: Yes email address. If in the nameinfo table the row has an email address of xyz@whatever.com and there is a row in events table with an email address of xyz@whatever.com I'd like to show that he went to those events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run another query inside the loop. Here I am calling a function to do the job:

```
$i=0;
$link = ""\\your database connection
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nameinfo WHERE account='$a'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
    $i++;

    echo "<div>";
    echo "<table><tr style='font-weight:bold;color:green;font-size:9pt;text-align:left;'><td  style='text-align:left;'>";
    echo "<button class='toggles' id='".$i."'/>"; echo $row['fullname']."</button>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td  >";
    echo $row['target'];
    echo "</td><td >";
    echo $row['lname'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td >";
    echo $row['fname'];
    echo "</td><td >";
    echo $row['title'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td >";
    echo $row['company'];
    echo "</td><td >";
    echo $row['address'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td >";
    echo $row['address2'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['city'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['state'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['zip'];
    echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
    echo $row['email'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['officenum'];
    echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
    echo $row['cellnum'];
    echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
    echo $row['date'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['rep'];
    echo "</td></tr></table></div>";
    echo "<div style='width:100%;background:#000;color:#fff;display:none;' id='show-".$i."'>";
        getEvent($row['email']);//Pass the email to the function here
    echo "</div>";
}    

function getEvent($email){  
    global $link;       
    $evant = "";
    $query =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE email='$email'", $link);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){    
        $event = $event . $row["event_name"] . "<br />";
        //Format this however you wish to format
    }   
    return $event;
}

<script>
$("button.toggles").click(function() {
       var value = $(this).attr('id');
       $("#show-" + value).toggle();
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: That didn't work. It broke the toggle on the div and doesn't display information.

Comment: We are missing the connection to database here. Lets say your connect variable is called $link... we will need that in function. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your help. This is my first time using stackoverflow, you have been a huge help!